# Suggestions for a light-weight PHP screen scraping library

Tags: library, php, scraping

Title says it all really, I need a library that allows me to quickly get data out of a HTML page without having to fully implement downloading, redirects, etc. in detail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yepp. I suggest to [edit] your question and add some more details :) Some background (examples of what you want to achieve) would be helpful, also what should be scraped and what format the output should have. Besides, AFAIK download+redirect-handling is dealt with by `file_get_contents()` when you pass it the right `context`. For parsing, you can use the DOM functionality easily (provided the document is not too crappy). I'm doing that for many things, and it's usually just a few lines of code (depending on the amount of data entities to retrieve).

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Goutte, a simple PHP Web Scraper](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte).

> Goutte is a screen scraping and web crawling library for PHP.
>
> Goutte provides a nice API to crawl websites and extract data from the HTML/XML responses.